# How to use window IsActive="False" state trigger in uwp?

Tags: c#, uwp, window, visualstates

In wpf it's looks like this:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsActive, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" Value="false">
   <Setter />
</DataTrigger>
```

Answer (score 0):

UWP uses `StateTrigger` assigned to a [`VisualState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.VisualState#examples) and the `VisualStateManager` to realize triggers. The equivalent in UWP is:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
  <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ControlStates">
    <VisualState x:Name="IsActive">
      <VisualState.StateTriggers>
        <StateTrigger IsActive="{Binding IsActive, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" />
     </VisualState.StateTriggers>
     <VisualState.Setters>
       <Setter Target="..." Value="..." />
     </VisualState.Setters>
   </VisualState>
  </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```